# Pass array to another page with POST

Tags: php, arrays, post

How to pass a array to another page?
  what is the problem with my code?

```
$r=mysql_query("select * from pay where PayID=1");
$ar=array();
while ($record=mysql_fetch_array($r))
{
array_push($ar,$record['Reserveid']);
}
var_dump($ar);
$url = 'http://--/a.php';
$client = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POST,1);
$data = array(
    'r' =>$ar
);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt ($client, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($client, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$response = curl_exec($client);
echo $response;
```

### a.php

```
$r=$_POST['r'];
var_dump($r);
```

output is

```
array(3) { ...... } 
-------------------------------
string(5) "Array"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data` should be:

```
$data = http_build_query(array(
    'r' => $ar
));
```

Comment: @a.v Because PHP's cURL expects query string for POST data, not an array.